# kernel: bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unknown ioctl 0x40187a22

Tags: kernel-modules, raspberry-pi, raspbian, lightdm

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. Towards the end of the startup log, I see this error. I believe it has been there a while, and I'm not sure what it may imply.

```
kernel: bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unknown ioctl 0x40187a22
```

It is included around the launch of `lightdm`. Here is the log section:

```
Nov 27 13:20:30 raspberrypi lightdm[619]: ** (lightdm:619): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedeskt
Nov 27 13:20:30 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Nov 27 13:20:31 raspberrypi kernel: bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unknown ioctl 0x40187a22
Nov 27 13:20:31 raspberrypi kernel: cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
Nov 27 13:20:32 raspberrypi lightdm[619]: ** (process:670): WARNING **: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedeskt
Nov 27 13:20:32 raspberrypi lightdm[670]: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user XX by (uid=0)
```

I should perhaps note that the default user `pi` doesn't exist anymore, why `lightdm` may be complaining about doing stuff for `uid=0`.

Comment: Can you log in to a graphical session? After a reboot I no longer can, and "bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Unknown ioctl 0x40187a22" is the only error I see in logs. My pi has a destroyed i2c interface, but that did not prevent graphical login. And the default user pi is unchanged.

Comment: @MKaama Yes, `startx` for Raspbian GUI OS works for me. I'm still not sure what this `iotcl` error designates.